# Vscode starts to show no color for Javascript reserved words

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme

Yesterday I opened my Vscode like usual, and for no reason, the Javascript reserved words haven't highlighted color

[image: code without colors]

***Observations***:

**1**.  I tried reconfiguring the file color theme (with no success).

**2.** I tried reconfiguring the file type association (with no success).

**3.** I tried to remove and install Prettier again (with no success).

**4**.  I did not change the Vscode configuration before the problem started.

**5**.  I did not update or upgrade anything on the Operational System before the problem started.

**6**.  Only Javascript has this problem.

**7**.  The problem doesn't happen when in the Devcontainer.

**8**.  I tried to reopen Vscode (with no success).

**9**.  I tried to restart the Pc (with no success).

**10**. Today without doing anything, the color highlight starts to work again.

**11**. I still don't understand what happened Yesterday.

Comment: Is it also broken for the top of the file?

Comment: Yes, on top of the file or copied all code on a new file, the problem continued. It happened in all projects, NestJS, ReactJS, or a simple JS file.

Comment: In the bottom right corner, you have a file type. Try to change it

Comment: I had the same issue yesterday. If you use the `TypeScript extension` from microsoft restore It's version to some days ago and It should work.

Comment: You're right, it was Microsoft's TypeScript extension. Thank some much everybody!